# How to Apply Globalization On Web User Control in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, globalization, webusercontrol

i have applied globalization on default page but it is not applied on Web User Control.
I have created Header.ascx and put two linkButton one for  English and second for spanish.
i am using code on header.ascx form code is below ... .

this code for english

```
 protected void lbtnEng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
        cookie.Value = "en";
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
        Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

    }
```

this code for Spanish language

```
protected void lbtnSpan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = "es-mx";
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =  new CultureInfo("es-mx");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-mx");
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
  }
```

this code change language on default page label text but not on web user control label
declare control on default page

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_test" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Test %>"></asp:Label>
```

and on web control

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_test" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Test %>"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set only one language at a time. In order to achieve your task .Use static strings or Take one resource file which consist of key value pairs. This is an example for submit key.

```
ResourceFileForStaticStrings.resx

Key                   Value
submitEnglish         Submit
submitSpanish         Presentar
```

Store it in a session or a cookie: Try the below one

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session("es").ToString)  
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session("es").ToString)
```

Comment: ya i have created two resource file one Resource.resx for english and second is Resource.es-mx.resx for spanish and in this also set key and values

Comment: i know you have created 2 resource files. but the thing is you cannot set two languages at a time. In order to display more than 2 languages in one page. So create separate resource file as i explained above.

Comment: i did't get i am set one language at time when we click on link button  and also create two seperate file one is resource.resx for english and second is Resource.es-mx for spanish

Comment: i think you going to display two languages in one page. Am i right?

Comment: no i am creating two link button one for english and second for spanish when user click on spanish then site translated on spanish such as like i mentioned above i have created two resource file

Comment: Store it in a session or a cookie: Try the below one System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session("es").ToString)

     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session("es").ToString)

Comment: where i have to place this code on web user control linkbutton click whether on default page load event

Comment: When ever you click on lbtnSpan button. on code behind of web user control.

Comment: now i am trying  same code  which one i have posted at top at home its working not in office i did't get why this happening

Comment: May be cookies are disabled in your office system.check your browser cookie setings